# Protect deleting/renaming file in git repository

Tags: git, delete-file, husky, git-husky

Is it possible to have one or more files in a git repository that can be changed but not deleted or renamed?
The use case is about a repository setup where multiple `env` files can only be tweaked by developers but prevent them to accidentally delete or rename the files as the CI would break without them with that exact name.

One idea I had was to write some sort of bash or node script and hook it in a `pre-commit` git hook with [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky), but I am not sure how would that script would look like yet.
Another idea was to initially set the right file permissions on the `env` files but I am not sure those would be retained in a git repository cloned on different OS platforms.

Anyway maybe there are some more idiomatic and smart ways to do this. Quite surprisingly I could not find anything online... So all sorts of creative solutions are accepted if not too cumbersome.
thanks!

Comment: CI breaking *is* the prevention. You can't (and shouldn't) use Git for this.

Comment: Hi @meagar, thx for your comment, would you mind expanding it a bit? How would you approach this? thanks!

Comment: If a chance in the repo causes CI to fail, then don't merge that change. You don't need specific checks for specific types of failures, and I wouldn't spend any time trying to prevent people from renaming files. Developers should know not to do that, and if they *do* do it, and CI fails, their changes won't be merged and they won't make the same mistake a second time.